# Choice field in Django registration forms look inactive, but works

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-2.2

So the thing is that I added custom user model

```
models.py

class CustomUserModel(AbstractUser):

pass

Morasko = "Morasko"
Piatkowo = "Piątkowo"

district_choices = [
(Morasko, "Morasko"),
(Piatkowo, "Piątkowo"),
]

district = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=district_choices, default=district_choices[0])
```

Field 'district' is supposed to be a choice field with two options. Here is custom registration form I am using.

```
forms.py

class NewUserForm(UserCreationForm):

district = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=CustomUserModel.district_choices)

class Meta(UserCreationForm):
    model = CustomUserModel
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'district', 'password1', 'password2')

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(NewUserForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    user.district = self.cleaned_data['district']
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

My html registration file:

```
register.html

{% extends "map_neigh/home.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class='container'>
  <div id='inner'>
    <br>
    <form method="POST">

      {% csrf_token %}
      {{form.as_p}}

      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>

    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    If you already have an account <a href="/login"><strong>log in.</strong></a>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Choice field actually works - users are saved in DB with clicked district, but it looks inactive and I have no clue why. Clicking it doesn't change the appearance, if I hove over one of options pointer doesn't change neither.
Below screenshot of the registration form.
[image: As you can see hove does not work, clicking doesn't change anything neither]

```
home.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<title>NoFence</title>
  {% load static %}
  <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "{% static 'style.css' %}"/>

<!--bootstrap-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!--jQuery links -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<!--leaflet links -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet.locatecontrol@0.65.2/dist/L.Control.Locate.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet.locatecontrol@0.65.2/src/L.Control.Locate.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<!--toast-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<!--jquery scripts -->
<script>

</script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--navigation bar-->
  {% include "map_neigh/includes/navbar.html" %}
  <!--user messages-->
  {% include "map_neigh/includes/messaging.html" %}

  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}

</body>
</html>


style.css

body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
background-color:#808080;
}
#menu_res {
position: relative;
padding-left: 15%;
font-size: 1.25vw;
}

#menu {
position: relative;
padding-left: 15%;
padding-top: 1.5vw;
padding-bottom: 0.9vw;
font-size: 1.5vw;
}

html{
scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#inner {
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: It could be your styling. Can you also post your "map_neigh/home.html" file?

Comment: Of course, question edited! Although after your suggestion I tried to run registration form without any css files and the chose field didn't change...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**models.py**

```
class CustomUserModel(AbstractUser):
    Morasko = "Morasko"
    Piatkowo = "Piątkowo"

   district_choices = (
       (Morasko, "Morasko"),
       (Piatkowo, "Piątkowo"),
   )

   district = models.CharField(
                 max_length=15, 
                 choices=district_choices, 
                 default=Morasko)
```

In your forms.py, your UserCreationForm needs to be a ModelForm, or you can just directly define it like this.
**forms.py**

```
class NewUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerUserModel
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'district', 'password1', 'password2')            
        widgets = {
            'district': forms.RadioSelect,
        }
```